# Authentication Provider Spring Security 5

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class with use an `AuthenticationProvider`

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(fusionAuthProvider);
}
```

Then in `fusionAuthProvider` in the authenticate() method is the flow to authenticate.
I'm developing and API RESTful. So, there is a way that I can say that i want to use that provider when i hit a certain endpoint like "/login_with_that_provider", using a controller or something like that?

Comment: An endpoint and a provider are connected through the authentication token (for example, the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`). An authentication provider can specify which token class it processes (through the `supports` method). You have to write (1) a filter that creates a unique token (subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationToken`) when "/login_with_that_provider" is hit and (2) a provider that supports that token. After that you can call authenticate method of the authentication manager in the filter to authenticate the request.

Comment: And what happens if I already have a tool that generates a token. I am using FusionAuth, i just call the API with username and password, and that returns a token. How is the flow in this case?

Comment: Sure, simply put your implementation of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` in the spring security filter chain and then create an `Authentication` object (based on your call to API) and pass it to `successfulAuthentication` method. You don't need any provider and you don't need to call authentication manager.